# Upgrading from Spring Security 3.x to 4.x

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-cas

```
<bean id="channelProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter">
      <property name="channelDecisionManager" ref="channelDecisionManager"/>
      <property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <security:filter-security-metadata-source request-matcher="regex" use-expressions="true">
          <security:intercept-url pattern="\A/login.*\Z" access="REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL"/>
          <security:intercept-url pattern="\A/Home.*\Z" access="REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL"/>
          <security:intercept-url pattern="\A/.*\Z" access="ANY_CHANNEL"/>
        </security:filter-security-metadata-source>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

The above snippet is throwing error on migration to Spring Security 4.x. Please let me know if there is a solution. I checked the migration guide but it does not mention any solution for this. This snippet is working fine with Spring Security 3.x.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceBindingGenerator': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'channelProcessingFilter' defined in URL [jar:file:xxxxx.jar!/META-INF/spring-security.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [ANY_CHANNEL, REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL, REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768) [catalina.jar:8.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'channelProcessingFilter' defined in URL [jar:file:/xxxxxx.jar!/META-INF/spring-security.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [ANY_CHANNEL, REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL, REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426) ~[springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [ANY_CHANNEL, REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL, REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.afterPropertiesSet(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You should use the `requires-channel` attribute with possible values of `http`, `https` and `any`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your `intercept-url` definitions like this:

```xml
<!-- old -->
<security:intercept-url 
  pattern="\A/.*\Z" 
  access="ANY_CHANNEL"/>

<!-- new -->
<security:intercept-url 
  pattern="\A/.*\Z" 
  access="hasRole(...)" 
  requires-channel="any" />
```

According to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.x/reference/html/ns-config.html#ns-requires-channel) you can use this vales for `requires-channel`:

> The available options are "http", "https" or "any". Using the value "any" means that either HTTP or HTTPS can be used.

Comment: Thanks. I declared the configuration as above. <security:intercept-url pattern="\A/Login.*\Z" access="isAnonymous()"  requires-channel="https"/>. Now I am getting below error \nConfiguration problem: Unexpected failure during bean definition parsing
Offending resource: URL [jarxxxxxxx.jar!/META-INF/spring-security.xml]
Bean 'channelProcessingFilter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The attribute 'requires-channel' isn't allowed here.
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:xxxxxx.jar!/META-INF/spring-security.xml

Comment: I am using Spring 4.3.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Set use-expressions="false". According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access-web), this value is set to true if access is an expression to be evaluated,

```
<security:filter-security-metadata-source use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:filter-security-metadata-source>
```

else false:

```
<security:filter-security-metadata-source request-matcher="regex" use-expressions="false">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="\A/.*\Z" access="ANY_CHANNEL"/>
</security:filter-security-metadata-source>
```